# Define an abstract async method even if not all overrides are async?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, abstract, tap

Consider having an abstract class to derive various types of actions (in the sense of commands that can be executed) from. Some of these actions execute asynchronous (like wait, receive) others execute synchronous (i.e. display something on the gui). At the moment I only have one abstract async method in the base class:

```
public abstract class Action
{ 
    // ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the action type specific routines.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract Task<ActionResult> ExecuteAsync(); 
}
```

In the overrides of derived classes I use TaskCompletionSource for synchronous and asynchronous actions. On one hand I like the fact that from a caller perspective it’s a uniform interface. But on the other hand I read that its bad API design to pretend to be async if the code is actually synchronous in case of synchronous. The only other option I see is to have an additional synchronous

```
protected abstract ActionResult Execute();
```

method and a property

```
protected bool IsAsync { get; };
```

to decide whatever to call the synchronous or the asynchronous method. But I don’t like the idea of having to handle two different ways to execute a single action.
Is there a best practice for abstract async methods if not all overrides are asynchronous?

Comment: Actually I like the idea to handle it with two different methods. Because they are in fact different actions. One is async, one not. Thats a different concept and it needs to be stressed out with different methods. There are lot of methods in the framework that do work the same.

Comment: Can you have two abstract classes: one for synchronous actions and the other for asynchronous? It would be a clearer design.
Also Task<T> can be considered as an ability to execute asynchronously. For example, MSDN says: "The Task<TResult> class represents a single operation that returns a value and that usually executes asynchronously". Note the word "usually".

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they encourage me to separate sync and async methods. Two abstract classes would also be an option and I like it better than having a property to distinguish between sync and async actions in my domain model.